# FTP command to copy files and subfolders of a ftp directory

Tags: ftp, get, copy, ftp-client

How can i download or get all files and subfolders of a ftp folderby using a ftp command in windows OS? if i use mget then it will copy all files with in a ftp folder but i want to download all files and subfolders.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Theres is no explicit command in the ftp implementaion for recursive slurp a hole server. The implemention of such a functinaltity must be on the client side. GUI FTP Clients like Filezilla have this feature, also cli linux client lftp with the 'mirror' command.

Greetings.